# Boot iOS directly into Airplane Mode

Tags: iphone, ios, airplane-mode

My phone is switched off and I want to boot into airplane mode directly, without going online for even a split second (so quickly booting and opening control center and tapping airplane isn't an option as I'll be online for a few seconds).

How do I do this? (and no, I don't have a practical Faraday cage or somewhere with no reception available)

Comment: May I ask why you can't go online?

Comment: @IronCraftMan does it matter?

Comment: Yes. Possibly an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @IronCraftMan not really an XY problem as how I got into "non-Airplane mode" is straightforward and irrelevant. anyway, if it *really* matters, my phone is off for various reasons and the moment I turn it on, some other ends will be getting delivery notifications of some messages, which I don't want. if I can safely boot into airplane mode without going online even for a second, then I'll be avoiding that. I've got some completely offline apps music and games that I want to use on my phone, I want to access them.

Comment: I think I've solved your problem! See my answer below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. You can, however, make it so your phone does not have internet access when it boots.

1. Remove your iPhone's Sim Card (you can get a sim card remover on Amazon for maybe $3).
2. Scan for wifi and ensure no wifi is reachable in case the device is paired with a network.
3. Disable any hotspots (Bluetooth or wifi-based)
4. Boot up your phone normally, and it will have no method to connect to the internet.

Note that Bluetooth and gps will still be active since you won't be in full airplane mode, so this probably isn't suitable for a plane flight.

Optional: To ensure no pre-existing wifi or Bluetooth connections, perform a factory reset of your phone via iTunes or Apple Configurator or other tool.

Comment: Yep, that would work. It's a shame there's no standard way of doing this. Anyway, thanks. BTW leaving Bluetooth/GPS doesn't have any effect on flight safety, I always leave it on.

Comment: I did some more research, and I believe you are right about Bluetooth and GPS (I edited my answer, thanks for that). I really wonder how Apple would make a standard way of doing this. A special button for airplane mode boot-ups? Control iPhone even when completely powered off? Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Maybe pressing home button while booting up? Or keep pressing the power button for some extra seconds until bootup. I can't think of another option. It may be useful.

Comment: There are faraday bags sized to fit phones, which should do the same thing.